# How to hide background outside image using css?

Tags: html, css

How to hide background outside image using css ?

When test my code. it's will be show like this

[image]

but i want to apply my code to show like this

[image]

how can i do ?

```css
.plainmodal-close{
     position: absolute;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    right: 50%;
    top: 0px;
    background: url(http://www.entypo.com/images/circle-with-cross.svg) no-repeat;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    }
```

```html
<div class="plainmodal-close"></div>
```

Comment: Try not to use external sites when providing information for questions e.g. images (imgur) and code (jsfiddle). Just use the built-in functionality supplied by SO when adding/editing your questions. Information logged on external sites can be lost or deleted over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.plainmodal-close{
    position: absolute;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    right: 50%;
    top: 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    box-sizing:
}
.plainmodal-close > span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 30px;
    height: 7px;
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.plainmodal-close > span::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 30px;
    height: 7px;
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="plainmodal-close">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

How about this?

I would like to recommend using PURE CSS.

I can't suggest an answer.

I just can suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to do it the way you want to as images cannot be modified via css. You can add some style to the container hosting the image but thats about it.

However, an even better way to do this is to use web-fonts like [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) and play with the css to get it how you like it.

```css
.fa-stack .fa.fa-times 
{ 
  color: red; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.fa-stack .fa.fa-circle 
{ 
  opacity:0.0;  
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-times fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because box-shadow is fun :

```css
.plainmodal-close{
  position: absolute;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  right: 50%;
  top: 0px;
  background: url(http://www.entypo.com/images/circle-with-cross.svg) no-repeat center center;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="plainmodal-close"></div>
```

Comment: Simple and effective :) I like it.